# Why is the variable not working properly on the CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created --item-width as a var variable in JavaScript. I thought it would work properly on the CSS, but it's not working properly. What should I do? I'm still a beginner, so I think I did something wrong. Help me.
I am writing again because I was banished from writing. I look forward to your kind cooperation.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>marquee_text</title>
    <link href="CSS/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/script.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrap">
        <div class="marquee-text">
            <div class="marquee-text__wrapper" data-controller="marquee">
                <a href="#" class="item-link" target="_blank"></a>
                <div class="marquee-text__item">
                    <strong>Marquee Text</strong>
                    <svg class="marquee-text__separator" height="19" width="19" viewBox="0 0 100 95.11">
                        <polygon points="50 0 65.45 31.31 100 36.33 75 60.7 80.9 95.11 50 78.86 19.1 95.11 25 60.7 0 36.33 34.55 31.31 50 0"/>
                    </svg>
                    <span>Marquee Text</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
@charset "UTF-8";

:root {
  --item-width: 0;
}

.marquee-text {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #222;
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #fff;
}

.marquee-text__wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
}

.marquee-text__item {
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.marquee-text__separator {
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
    margin: 0 10px;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    fill: currentColor;
}

.marquee-text a:hover {
    opacity: 0;
}
@keyframes marquee-text-ani {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    /* This code is not working. */
    transform: translate3d(-(var(--item-width))'px', 0, 0);
  }
}
```

```
setTimeout(()=>{
    this.move()
}, 200)

function move() {
    const $marqueeTop = document.querySelector(".marquee-text__wrapper");
    const $marqueeTopItem = document.querySelector(".marquee-text__wrapper>div");
    const $root = document.querySelector(":root");
    const itemWidth= $marqueeTopItem.clientWidth;
    
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        let marqueeTopItem = $marqueeTopItem.cloneNode(!0);
        $marqueeTop.appendChild(marqueeTopItem);
    }
    
    // This variable is not working in CSS.
    $root.style.setProperty(`--item-width`, itemWidth);
    $marqueeTop.style.animation = `marquee-text-ani 4s linear 1s forwards infinite`;
}
```

Comment: Your snippet doesn't work and you haven't provided a working demo anywhere else. How do you expect anyone to follow your steps?!

Comment: Your steps don't make any sense. I have no idea what they mean. Presumably a _working demo_ might shed some light on it but it is far from obvious what you're the problem actually is!

Comment: That’s because you can’t use CSS variables like that with string interpolation. If you want to convert it to a negative value, you will need to use `calc()` and multiply it by `-1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the code like Terry gave me the comment, and it works well. Thank you.

```
transform: translate3d(calc((-1px) * var(--item-width)), 0, 0);
```